# Initiating the Google+ Sign-In flow with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm following the current [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow) and for some reason when ever I click on the Sign in with Google button nothing seems to happen and I'm not entirely sure why. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>

</head>
<body>

    <meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="782332402251-os0n348u3v5vaq5kff87f5pc65ib6i19.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
    <meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="http://schema.org/AddAction" />
    <meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=render" async defer>
         /* Executed when the APIs finish loading */
         function render() 
         {
           // Additional params including the callback, the rest of the params will
           // come from the page-level configuration.
           var additionalParams = {
             'callback': signinCallback
           };

           // Attach a click listener to a button to trigger the flow.
           var signinButton = document.getElementById('signinButton');

           signinButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
             gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams); // Will use page level configuration
           });
         }


         function signinCallback(authResult) 
         {
              if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
                // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
                // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
                document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
              } else {
                // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
                // Possible error values:
                //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
                //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
                //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
                console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
              }
         }
    </script>


    <button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are loading `platform.js` twice. Try removing the first one.

Comment: Also, try adding a `console.log` inside the `render` function, to see if its actually being called.

Comment: Got rid of the first call to the platform.js file and used the console.log but nothing happens. I assume here for some reason the js isn't being called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a mistake in the tutorial. Emedding Javascript within a script tag with a `src` attribute is [not valid](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) in HTML5. You need to move your code into a separate script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// your code here
</script>
```

See here - http://jsfiddle.net/7umb41z2/

Comment: I was literally dying for not finding the issue! Thanks a lot!